# AtTask Document supported extensions

Tags: document, file-extension, attask

I'm having issue to open a html file in workfront under documents, it couldn't able to open attached html file. What kind of extensions does it supports?

Comment: HTML is supported what errors are you getting? If you are having trouble uploading/downloading thought the UI I suggest submitting a ticket to the help desk.

Comment: It is not supporting preview the HTML files.

Comment: For HTML files you need to download the file first and then open it.